# Flask - Postgresql - relation does not exist

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to create new database (migrate from sqlite to postgresql) for my flask App. When the app starts and call the function `create_all()` the app send the error `relation "user" does not exists"` for the following event listener :

```py
@event.listen_for(User.__table__, 'after_create')
def create_default_user(*args, **kwargs): 
    print("Create User Table - Default User")
    db.session.add(User(username="admin", email="admin@plop.com", password=generate_password_hash("admin", "sha256")))
    db.session.commit()
```

If I create new sqlite db (*"sqlite://db.sqlite"*) all works fine, But if i want to initiate postgresql database (*"postgresql://test:mysuperpassword@172.17.0.2:5432/flask"*) i got the error.

Someone know where i did a mistake ?

Comment: Typically the postgres database must already exists and you should be able to successfully connect to it with the password/username you are supplying to flask. Is this the case?

Comment: Yes the base exists, i can connect via psql, but the table aren't created for the moment (i want to create it when flask app is initiated)

Comment: You will probably have to create the required tables yourself. Is there any particular reason you expect otherwise here?

Comment: I want to expose the app as pods on kubernetes, i wanted to auto initiate the db without manual intervention, i wanted to see if it's possible

Comment: First mistake was starting developing on the database you did not plan on using for production. Pretty sure that lead directly to this error which I'm guessing is due to case sensitivity for relation names. Sqlite is not case sensitive, Postgres is. I bet that in the database the table is named `User` and that the migration is looking for `user`.

Comment: i check with both databases during all the developpement process, and it was working with databases i instancied manually (with debug functions) and i just implemented the auto instanciation and wanted to try my CI but it failed ^^
I will manualy create the db for the moment, the time i find a solution 
Thanks for your answers :)